# How to write unit test cases for rake tasks in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rake

Hi all I have this situation , I need to write unit test cases for rake tasks in my rails application but i could not figure out a way to do that. Did any one try that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is this..

1. Write your logic which will run on a rake task inside a model or class.
2. Write unit test for that model.
3. Finally call that method inside your rake task.

Comment: http://pivotallabs.com/users/shagemann/blog/articles/1967-test-your-rake-tasks-
I tested the rake task by invoking the rake task from the testcases and verified the result with database by loading the expected records.
http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/11/ruby-testing-rake-tasks.html
The above link provides a more robust way to do testing the rake task.

Answer (score 0):

I found out [this](https://www.eliotsykes.com/test-rails-rake-tasks-with-rspec) link for writing test cases using rspec.
Short and crisp test cases

Basically, create a module which will parse the name of the rake task, and make us available the keyword task, on which we could call `expect { task.execute }.to output("your text\n").to_stdout`

Here's how you will create the file,

```
module TaskExampleGroup extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
    let(:task_name) { self.class.top_level_description.sub(/\Arake /, "") }
    let(:tasks) { Rake::Task }

    # Make the Rake task available as `task` in your examples:
    subject(:task) { tasks[task_name] }
    end
end
```

Add this in the rspec initializer file

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

    # Tag Rake specs with `:task` metadata or put them in the spec/tasks dir
    config.define_derived_metadata(:file_path => %r{/spec/tasks/}) do |metadata|
    metadata[:type] = :task
    end

    config.include TaskExampleGroup, type: :task

    config.before(:suite) do
    Rails.application.load_tasks
    end
end
```

Comment: Please add some context around this link. It may turn invalid, leaving a broken answer behind.